# How to get async result in parent function? TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have next code structure:

```js
import {socket} from './socket';

class A{
Execute(...args[]){
   //logic with Promises
   SomeAsyncMethod1().then(fulfilled1);

   function fulfilled1(){
     SomeAsyncMethod2(args).then(fulfilled2);
   }

   function fulfilled2(filled_result){
     //(1)
   }
 }
}

class B{
  private a_obj: A;

  constructor(){
    a_obj = new A();
  }

  Method1(one: string){
    a_obj.Execute(one);
  }

  Method2(one: number, two: any){
    a_obj.Execute(one, two);
  }
}

Class C{
  interface Ids {
    [id: string]: any;
  }
  let instances: Ids = {};
  instances["1"] = new B();
  instances["W"] = new B();

  CallMethod(callerId: string, objectId: string, methodName: string, args: any[])
    instances[objectId][methodName](...args);
    //(!) (2)
  }
}
```

"(!)" - There I want to send `filled_result` from `fulfilled2` function to client with `clientId` via `socket`. But how I can get there `filled_result`?
Like this:

```js
  CallMethod(callerId: string, objectId: string, methodName: string, args: any[])
    instances[objectId][methodName](...args);
    socket.send_results(callerId, filled_result);
  }
```

The problem is that in (1) I don't know `clientId`, in (2) I dont know `filled_result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding map with `requestId`(generated in `Execute` method) as key and return it to parent function which set a `clientId` to map with returned key

```
import {socket} from './socket';

interface IStringMap {
  [key: string]: any;
}
const REQUEST_QUEUE: IStringMap = {};

GenerateRequestID() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  };

class A{
Execute(...args[]):string {
   let req_id = this.GenerateRequestID();

   //logic with Promises
   SomeAsyncMethod1().then(fulfilled1);

   function fulfilled1(){
     SomeAsyncMethod2(args).then(fulfilled2);
   }

   function fulfilled2(filled_result){
     socket.send_results(REQUEST_QUEUE[req_id], filled_result);
     delete REQUEST_QUEUE[req_id];
   }

   return req_id;
 }
}

class B{
  private a_obj: A;

  constructor(){
    a_obj = new A();
  }

  Method1(one: string){
    return a_obj.Execute(one);
  }

  Method2(one: number, two: any){
    return a_obj.Execute(one, two);
  }
}

Class C{
  interface Ids {
    [id: string]: any;
  }
  let instances: Ids = {};
  instances["1"] = new B();
  instances["W"] = new B();

  CallMethod(callerId: string, objectId: string, methodName: string, args: any[])
    let reqId = instances[objectId][methodName](...args);
    REQUEST_QUEUE[reqId] = callerId;
  }
}
```